# nginx+gunicorn+supervisor throwing intermittent HTTP 500 Errors

Tags: django, nginx, load, gunicorn

I have an application running nginx,django 1.5, gunicorn.

**Scenario 1**
When I load my application one time - it will show the page file with an underlying 200 HTTP response.

**Scenario 2**

However, if I *reload* this same page right after, it will show my HTTP 500 Default, but custom page.

**Scenario X**
If I reload again, it either will show Scenario 1 or Scenario 2 upon subsequent page reloads.

I looked at my access.log for nginx and...

it is showing information like for the 500 error page:

```
[05/Oct/2013:03:26:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 460 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"

 [05/Oct/2013:03:21:19 +0000] "GET /static/img/templated/base/subnav_back.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://mydomain.com/static/css/base.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"
```

it is showing information for a 200 HTTP response of:

```
[05/Oct/2013:03:18:25 +0000] "GET /static/img/templated/base/subnav_back.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7674 "http://mydomain.com/static/css/mysite_base.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"
```

nginx conf looks like:

```
server {
        server_name ec2-X-X-X-X.compute-1.amazonaws.com;
        access_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/error/access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/error/error.log warn;
        connection_pool_size 2048;

        root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/;

        location /static/ {
            alias /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/static/;
            #alias /static/;
            #root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }
```

error.log has:

```
2013/09/21 19:36:22 [error] 12680#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XX.XXX.XX.XXX, server: ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/", host: "www.mysite.com", referrer: "http://www.mysite.com/dir/"
```

Comment: What about your error log?

Comment: Please see updated error.log info above.

Comment: is something wrong with my proxy_pass setup?

Comment: I don't use nginx for Django so I have no clue, but hopefully you have more search terms to look for now!

Comment: I've been dealing with the "mystery subsequent page errors." This can be caused by Gunicorn processes not having reloaded the project source.  You can try running it with `--max-requests=1` while you debug, this should at least keep the behavior consistent between reloads.